# How to copy AMI by using cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, aws-cloudformation, devops

Is it possible in Cloudformation that we can copy AWS **ami** from one region to another.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you can't do this without a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

The resource would be a lambda function which would use AWS SDK (e.g. boto3) to [copy_image](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.copy_image) from one region to the other.